# Migrating from UIWebView Event Listeners to WKWebView Event Listeners

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

So my goal is to migrate all of our existing UIWebViews to WKWebViews within our Xamarin.iOS forms project. I'm having some difficulty migrating a few things over. Here are a few examples:

Adding an event listener:

```
WebView.AddEventListener("javscriptRoutine", delegate (FireEventData arg) {
     //do something             
});
```

Event handler:

```
WebView.LoadStarted += (object sender, EventArgs e) => {
     //do something
};
```

These are 2 examples of UIWebView functionality that I'm having a difficult time migrating to WKWebView functionality. Are there any equivalent methods for these two methods within the WKWebView class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the Event handler you can use `WKNavigationDelegate`:

```
wkWebView.NavigationDelegate = new MyWKWebViewDelegate();

public class MyWKWebViewDelegate : WKNavigationDelegate
{
    //Method will fire when data begins to load.
    public override void DidStartProvisionalNavigation(WKWebView webView, WKNavigation navigation)
    {

    }
}
```

For adding an event listener, do you want to use the JS method on iOS? If so, you can try:

```
wkWebView.EvaluateJavaScript("JSMethodNameString", delegate (NSObject result, NSError error)
{

});
```